# select random rows from the dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have three dataframes that I have joined together to create a single dataframe.

```
df_1 = df_1.withColumn('idx', monotonically_increasing_id())
df_2 = df_2.withColumn('idx', monotonically_increasing_id())
df_3 = df_3.withColumn('DATE', to_timestamp('DATE')) \
        .withColumn('idx', monotonically_increasing_id())

merged_df = df_1.join(df_2, ['idx']).join(df_3, ['idx']).drop('idx')
```

And I want to retrieve a set of random rows from it.

I don't do any sorting for the dataframes but when I use `limit`

```
random_choices_df = merged_df.limit(10)
random_choices_df.show()
```

`show` function always displays the same items in the same order.

How to retrieve a random set of rows? I thought `limit` supposed to do that but for some reason it preserves the order of items. I am running on a single machine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Sample](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample.html) function to take a random sample from your df and then limit the number of rows you need.

```py
>>> df=spark.range(10000).sample(0.1).limit(10).show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  4|
|  7|
| 13|
| 19|
| 36|
| 46|
| 82|
| 91|
|102|
+---+
```

```py
>>> df=spark.range(10000).sample(0.1).limit(10).show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  6|
| 10|
| 11|
| 24|
| 28|
| 37|
| 49|
| 50|
| 72|
+---+
```